# Efficiently Iterate Through Datetime Index to Set Time Boundaries

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, timedelta, datetimeindex

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
                       col1     col2    col3
2020-01-02 08:50:00    360.0    -131.0  -943.0
2020-01-02 08:52:01    342.0    -130.0  -1006.0
2020-01-02 08:55:04    321.0    -130.0  -997.0
... ... ... ...
2022-01-03 14:44:56    1375.0   -91.0   -728.0
2022-01-03 14:50:57    1381.0   -118.0  -692.0
2022-01-03 14:50:58    1382.0   -115.0  -697.0
2022-01-03 14:50:59    1390.0   -111.0  -684.0
2022-01-03 14:55:58    1442.0   -106.0  -691.0
```

I want a function that obtains the indices that:

Are **NOT** within a specific time (e.g., 5 minutes) of each other.

For example:

`masked_df = time_mask(df.index, pd.Timedelta(minutes=5))`

`masked_df:`

```
                       col1     col2    col3
2020-01-02 08:50:00    360.0    -131.0  -943.0
2020-01-02 08:55:04    321.0    -130.0  -997.0
... ... ... ...
2022-01-03 14:44:56    1375.0   -91.0   -728.0
2022-01-03 14:50:57    1381.0   -118.0  -692.0
2022-01-03 14:55:58    1442.0   -106.0  -691.0
```

The function `time_mask` should obtain the **first** index that is not within 5 minutes of the previously added index. Below is my *iterative* attempt to solve this problem:

```
def get_clean_ix_from_rolling(idx, time_delt):
    
    clean_ix = []
    prev_ix = idx[0]
    clean_ix.append(prev_ix)
    for i, x in enumerate(idx):
        if((x-prev_ix) >= time_delt):
            clean_ix.append(x)
            prev_ix = x

    ix = pd.to_datetime(clean_ix)
    return ix
```

How can I speed up my code above?

Answer (score 0):

Shift your index by one row using `.shift()` and subtract it by the value of next value using `.sub()`. Get the minute difference using `astype` and check if it is equal to your time_delta using `.eq()`. Finally mask the index and get the results:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create some sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(index=["2020-01-02 08:50:00",
                           "2020-01-02 08:55:04",
                           "2022-01-03 14:44:56",
                           "2022-01-03 14:50:57",
                           "2022-01-03 14:55:57",
                           "2022-01-03 14:56:57",
                           "2022-01-03 14:57:57",
                           "2022-01-03 14:58:57",
                           "2022-01-03 14:59:57"])
                                                      
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df
```

Output:

```
2020-01-02 08:50:00
2020-01-02 08:55:04
2022-01-03 14:44:56
2022-01-03 14:50:57
2022-01-03 14:55:57
2022-01-03 14:56:57
2022-01-03 14:57:57
2022-01-03 14:58:57
2022-01-03 14:59:57
```

---

```
time_delta = 5
idx = df.index.to_series()
s = idx.shift(-1).sub(idx).astype('timedelta64[m]').eq(time_delta)
df[~s]
```

Output:

```
2020-01-02 08:55:04
2022-01-03 14:44:56
2022-01-03 14:55:57
2022-01-03 14:56:57
2022-01-03 14:57:57
2022-01-03 14:58:57
2022-01-03 14:59:57
```

**Edit:**

I doubt that you can do what you described in the comments without an explicit for loop, in which case you'd better use `itertools()` or `itertuple()`. They will be faster, but I don't recommend using them either. Consider a change in approach like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Create some sample data
dates = ["2022-01-02 08:50:00",
                           "2022-01-02 08:55:04",
                           "2022-01-03 14:44:56",
                           "2022-01-03 14:50:57",
                           "2022-01-03 14:55:57",
                           "2022-01-03 15:00:57",
                           "2022-01-03 15:02:57",
                           "2022-01-03 15:05:57",
                           "2022-01-03 15:08:57",
                           "2022-01-03 15:10:57"]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.to_datetime(dates),
                  data=np.random.randint(low=-100, high=100, size=(10, 3))).add_prefix('col')
 df
```

Output:

```
                 col0 col1 col2
2022-01-02 08:50:00 1   43  71
2022-01-02 08:55:04 42  86  20
2022-01-03 14:44:56 -47 -97 64
2022-01-03 14:50:57 -5  76  59
2022-01-03 14:55:57 67  98  -36
2022-01-03 15:00:57 -44 85  33
2022-01-03 15:02:57 -8  14  67
2022-01-03 15:05:57 85  -84 -83
2022-01-03 15:08:57 -86 46  81
2022-01-03 15:10:57 -77 29  -63
```

---

```
df.resample('5min').agg('first').dropna(axis=0)
```

Output:

```
                    col0    col1    col2
2022-01-02 08:50:00 1.0     43.0    71.0
2022-01-02 08:55:00 42.0    86.0    20.0
2022-01-03 14:40:00 -47.0   -97.0   64.0
2022-01-03 14:50:00 -5.0    76.0    59.0
2022-01-03 14:55:00 67.0    98.0    -36.0
2022-01-03 15:00:00 -44.0   85.0    33.0
2022-01-03 15:05:00 85.0    -84.0   -83.0
2022-01-03 15:10:00 -77.0   29.0    -63.0
```

Comment: This is incorrect. I don't want just the next row to be 5 minutes away, but any row after that. So, the above output should not have 14:55 onwards

Comment: Resampling every 5 minutes and taking the first also does not work. Imagine having an index at 14:49 and another at 14:51. If 14:49 is the only index in that minute, it will violate the time rule.